# How to print a BMP from file or HDC

Tags: printing, bmp, gdi

I am trying to add printing capability to my Windows app. So far, I have succeeded in (1) painting the image into an HDC; (2) saving it as a BMP file; (3) creating a BITMAPINFOHEADER and pixmap in memory; and (4) creating an HBITMAP object.
How can I send any of these to my laser printer?  (I don't want to use any third-party app, but rather do it using API calls).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need to use the XPS Document API, unless your printer driver accepts bmp files as input (which seems unlikely). Another option is to generate output as a postscript file (many printers accept .ps files as input; at least, they used to. Check your printer's documentation).

If you choose the XPS document path, have a look here for the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/documents
Apparently, in Windows, you can now just send XPS documents to your print spooler, and it should work. I have not tested this.